# How to optimize this MySQL query .It takes nearly 2 secs to execute

Tags: sql-server, mysql

I recented converted my project from SQL SErver to MySQL .

I do see one my query which was executing faster in SQL server takes more time( 2 sec )  in mysql.

Am I doing anything wrong here .Help me to optimize it . Thank s

```
SELECT ReadingDateTime, SUM(DATA) AS PowerTotal FROM
LTMeterReading WHERE MeterID IN(59) and DataTypeID=48 and
ReadingDateTime >= '2010-04-01 12:00:00 AM' AND
ReadingDateTime < '2010-04-02 12:00:00 AM'
GROUP BY ReadingDateTime ORDER BY ReadingDateTime
```

Comment: Paste `SHOW CREATE TABLE` here please

Comment: ...and the output from 'EXPLAIN SELECT ReadingDateTime....'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it by Changing the MySQL table engine to MyISAM ,after which its very fast . Thanks guys .

Answer (score 1):

you can put indexes on the columns you check for, it might effect your insert time though.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add index, that covers `DataTypeID + MeterID + ReadingDateTime` in this particular order

Also - `ORDER BY` clause is obsolete here: after you have groupped by `ReadingDateTime` - data is already sorted ascendant by this field.

Comment: Be careful! Data may appear sorted but sorting is not guaranteed unless you use "order by". Some databases do not use conventional sorts when grouping (e.g. see Oracle's "Hash Group By").

Comment: @Lord Peter: in some reason i thought that this question is specifically about mysql, in which my words are correct.

Comment: hi , I tried indexing (DataTypeID , MeterID , ReadingDateTime) but it takes nearly 8 secs . More than before. And one more question how come SQL Server was so fast in it without indexing .

Comment: @Aashath: have you looked at query plan? How much records (in percent of all) does this query retrieve (without groupping, of course)?

Comment: @zerkms FYI:I execute this query in a loop where the MeterID get changing randomly .

Comment: @all I finally fixed it by Changing the MySQL table engine to MyISAM ,after which its very fast . But Indexing didnt work out much . But I Index as above  for my SQLite DB which has same table and its 10X faster after that . Thanks guys .

Answer (score 0):

how many rows in the table?
what's the data type of DATA?
any indexes on ReadingDateTime, MeterID, DataTypeID?

Comment: The table has nearly 1 Million records.I Havent indexed anything yet . DATA - Decimal

Comment: ! add some indexes **please** (and your query suggests you might look want to look at the business logic which lead to this code for optimizing it).